# Retrieving JSON object from a multipart request in nodejs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, formidable

```
var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(200).send('parsing error');
    }
});

var jsonObject;
var imageArray = [];

form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    console.log(file);
    if (file.type == 'application/json') {
        jsonObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'utf8'));
    } else if (file.type == 'image/jpeg') {
        imageArray.push(file.path);
    }
})
```

I'm using [formidable](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable) to handle a multipart request in node.js made from my iOS app, the request usually contains "n" number of images and a associated JSON object, the formidable middleware treats the JSON as an file and stores the file in the temporary download location and provides a path to the file, the code "jsonObject = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'utf8'));" reads the file and parses into a JSON object. Is this how it is supposed to work or is there a better way, that negates the superfluous file write and read from the disk and provides a parsed JSON obj directly.

PS - newbie to node.js, heck newbie to entire backend system with a very bad case OCD.

Comment: How are you sending the request? It seems like you should be able send the JSON as a "field type" instead of a "file type."

Comment: [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

I'm setting the content-type as application/json in the request.

Comment: Are you also adding `Content-Disposition` headers for each part?

Comment: Yes for both the image and json i'm setting the Content-Disposition as "form-data" along with custom name and a filename.

Comment: Well as long as you *don't* supply a filename for the `application/json` part, `formidable` shouldn't save it to a file, but keep it in memory as a non-file field instead.

Comment: Thanks mscdex, after looking into what you said about the filename part i was able to retrieve the json in the form.on('field', func).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formidable (and pretty much any other node form parsing modules) will only treat a particular part as a file if `filename` is set in the `Content-Disposition` header value (or possibly if `Content-Type` is `application/octet-stream`).